# How to concatenate lists from map properties in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have...

```
%{
  "errors" => %{
    "abc" => ["example", "something"],
    "xyz" => ["thing goes here"]
  }
}
```

I want...

```
["example", "something", "thing goes here"]
```

What's the cleanest way to get there?

Comment: _Shameless plug:_ using [`Iteraptor`](https://hexdocs.pm/iteraptor) library one might do it as `Iteraptor.reduce map, [], &[elem(&1, 1) | &2]` or in many other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need an order guarantee on which error keys come first, you could combine `Map.values/1` with `List.flatten/1` or use a comprehension to do it pretty easily

```rb
map = %{
  "errors" => %{
    "abc" => ["example", "something"],
    "xyz" => ["thing goes here"]
  }
}

map["errors"]
|> Map.values()
|> List.flatten()
#=> ["example", "something", "thing goes here"]

for {_key, items} <- map["errors"], item <- items, do: item
#=> ["example", "something", "thing goes here"]
```

Comment: I was making that much harder than it really was.  Thanks!